# Как сделать так, чтобы фигуры могли рисоваться на одном холсте?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, ui, рисование

Да у меня есть строчка `self.image_foreground.fill(Qt.white)` Но без неё рисование фигур "в реальном времени" не работает. Пробовал через список, но тогда не получается менять нормально цвет и толщину. Также после предварительной очистки холста не вставляется фотография. Помогите пожалуйста

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPen, QImage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QAction, QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QLineF, QRectF, QPointF


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 600, 600)

        mainMenu = self.menuBar()
        instmenu = mainMenu.addMenu("Инстументы")
        colormenu = mainMenu.addMenu("Цвет")
        sizemanu = mainMenu.addMenu("Толщина")
        file = mainMenu.addMenu("Файл")

        brush = QAction("Кисть", self)
        instmenu.addAction(brush)
        brush.triggered.connect(self.setBrush)

        line = QAction("Линия", self)
        instmenu.addAction(line)
        line.triggered.connect(self.setLine)

        circle = QAction("Круг", self)
        instmenu.addAction(circle)
        circle.triggered.connect(self.setCircle)

        rect = QAction("Прямоугольник", self)
        instmenu.addAction(rect)
        rect.triggered.connect(self.setRectangle)

        red = QAction("Красный", self)
        colormenu.addAction(red)
        red.triggered.connect(self.redColor)

        blue = QAction("Синий", self)
        colormenu.addAction(blue)
        blue.triggered.connect(self.blueColor)

        yellow = QAction("Желтый", self)
        colormenu.addAction(yellow)
        yellow.triggered.connect(self.yellowColor)

        black = QAction("Черный", self)
        colormenu.addAction(black)
        black.triggered.connect(self.blackColor)

        fpx = QAction("4", self)
        sizemanu.addAction(fpx)
        fpx.triggered.connect(self.four)

        epx = QAction("8", self)
        sizemanu.addAction(epx)
        epx.triggered.connect(self.eight)

        sipx = QAction("16", self)
        sizemanu.addAction(sipx)
        sipx.triggered.connect(self.sixteen)

        thpx = QAction("32", self)
        sizemanu.addAction(thpx)
        thpx.triggered.connect(self.thirtytwo)

        get = QAction('Вставить фото', self)
        file.addAction(get)
        get.triggered.connect(self.getImage)

        delete = QAction('Очистить', self)
        file.addAction(delete)
        delete.triggered.connect(self.deleteImage)

        self.image_foreground = QImage(self.size(), QImage.Format_ARGB32)
        self.image_foreground.fill(Qt.transparent)

        self.image_background = QImage(self.size(), QImage.Format_RGB32)
        self.image_background.fill(Qt.white)

        self.instrument = 'brush'

        self.brushColor = Qt.black
        self.brushSize = 8

        self.coords = QPointF()

    def getImage(self):
        filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "", "",
                                               "PNG(*.png);;JPEG(*.jpg *.jpeg);;All Files(*.*)")[0]
        if not filename:
            return
        self.image_background.load(filename)

    def deleteImage(self):
        self.image_foreground.fill(Qt.white)
        self.image_background.fill(Qt.white)
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawImage(self.rect(), self.image_background, self.image_background.rect())
        painter.drawImage(self.image_foreground.rect(), self.image_foreground)


    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton and self.instrument == 'brush':
            self.coords = event.pos()
        elif event.button() == Qt.LeftButton and self.instrument == 'line':
            self.coords = event.pos()
        elif event.button() == Qt.LeftButton and self.instrument == 'circle':
            self.coords = event.pos()
        elif event.button() == Qt.LeftButton and self.instrument == 'rectangle':
            self.coords = event.pos()
        self.update()
      

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton and self.instrument == 'brush':
            painter = QPainter(self.image_foreground)
            painter.setPen(QPen(self.brushColor, self.brushSize, Qt.SolidLine))
            painter.drawLine(self.coords, event.pos())
            self.coords = event.pos()
            self.update()
        elif event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton and self.instrument == 'line':
            self.image_foreground.fill(Qt.white)
            painter = QPainter(self.image_foreground)
            painter.setPen(QPen(self.brushColor, self.brushSize, Qt.SolidLine))
            painter.drawLine(self.coords, event.pos())
            self.update()
        elif event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton and self.instrument == 'circle':
            self.image_foreground.fill(Qt.white)
            painter = QPainter(self.image_foreground)
            painter.setPen(QPen(self.brushColor, self.brushSize, Qt.SolidLine))
            painter.drawEllipse(QRectF(self.coords, event.pos()))
            self.update()
        elif self.instrument == 'rectangle':
            self.image_foreground.fill(Qt.white)
            painter = QPainter(self.image_foreground)
            painter.setPen(QPen(self.brushColor, self.brushSize, Qt.SolidLine))
            painter.drawRect(QRectF(self.coords, event.pos()))
            self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if self.instrument == 'line':
            painter = QPainter(self.image_foreground)
            painter.setPen(QPen(self.brushColor, self.brushSize, Qt.SolidLine))
            painter.drawLine(QLineF(self.coords, event.pos()))
            self.update()
        elif self.instrument == 'circle':
            painter = QPainter(self.image_foreground)
            painter.setPen(QPen(self.brushColor, self.brushSize, Qt.SolidLine))
            painter.drawEllipse(QRectF(self.coords, event.pos()))
            self.update()
        elif self.instrument == 'rectangle':
            painter = QPainter(self.image_foreground)
            painter.setPen(QPen(self.brushColor, self.brushSize, Qt.SolidLine))
            painter.drawRect(QRectF(self.coords, event.pos()))
            self.update()

    def setBrush(self):
        self.instrument = 'brush'

    def setLine(self):
        self.instrument = 'line'

    def setCircle(self):
        self.instrument = 'circle'

    def setRectangle(self):
        self.instrument = 'rectangle'

    def four(self):
        self.brushSize = 4

    def eight(self):
        self.brushSize = 8

    def sixteen(self):
        self.brushSize = 16

    def thirtytwo(self):
        self.brushSize = 32

    def blackColor(self):
        self.brushColor = Qt.black

    def redColor(self):
        self.brushColor = Qt.red

    def blueColor(self):
        self.brushColor = Qt.blue

    def yellowColor(self):
        self.brushColor = Qt.yellow


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    wnd = Window()
    wnd.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону `enum` для инструмента :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного поколдовал над вашим кодом и заодно поменял использование картинки заднего фона

Попробуйте:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPen, QImage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QAction, QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QLineF, QRectF, QPointF


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 600, 600)

        mainMenu = self.menuBar()
        instmenu = mainMenu.addMenu("Инстументы")
        colormenu = mainMenu.addMenu("Цвет")
        sizemanu = mainMenu.addMenu("Толщина")
        file = mainMenu.addMenu("Файл")

        brush = QAction("Кисть", self)
        instmenu.addAction(brush)
        brush.triggered.connect(self.setBrush)

        line = QAction("Линия", self)
        instmenu.addAction(line)
        line.triggered.connect(self.setLine)

        circle = QAction("Круг", self)
        instmenu.addAction(circle)
        circle.triggered.connect(self.setCircle)

        rect = QAction("Прямоугольник", self)
        instmenu.addAction(rect)
        rect.triggered.connect(self.setRectangle)

        red = QAction("Красный", self)
        colormenu.addAction(red)
        red.triggered.connect(self.redColor)

        blue = QAction("Синий", self)
        colormenu.addAction(blue)
        blue.triggered.connect(self.blueColor)

        yellow = QAction("Желтый", self)
        colormenu.addAction(yellow)
        yellow.triggered.connect(self.yellowColor)

        black = QAction("Черный", self)
        colormenu.addAction(black)
        black.triggered.connect(self.blackColor)

        fpx = QAction("4", self)
        sizemanu.addAction(fpx)
        fpx.triggered.connect(self.four)

        epx = QAction("8", self)
        sizemanu.addAction(epx)
        epx.triggered.connect(self.eight)

        sipx = QAction("16", self)
        sizemanu.addAction(sipx)
        sipx.triggered.connect(self.sixteen)

        thpx = QAction("32", self)
        sizemanu.addAction(thpx)
        thpx.triggered.connect(self.thirtytwo)

        get = QAction('Вставить фото', self)
        file.addAction(get)
        get.triggered.connect(self.getImage)

        delete = QAction('Очистить', self)
        file.addAction(delete)
        delete.triggered.connect(self.deleteImage)

        self.image_foreground = QImage(self.size(), QImage.Format_ARGB32)
        self.image_foreground.fill(Qt.transparent)

        self.instrument = 'brush'

        self.brushColor = Qt.black
        self.brushSize = 8

        self.start_pos = QPointF()
        self.end_pos = QPointF()

        self.brush_points = []

    def getImage(self):
        filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self, "", "",
            "Images(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg);;PNG(*.png);;JPEG(*.jpg *.jpeg);;All Files(*.*)"
        )[0]
        if not filename:
            return
        self.image_foreground.load(filename)

    def deleteImage(self):
        self.image_foreground.fill(Qt.white)
        self.update()

    def draw(self, canvas):
        painter = QPainter(canvas)
        painter.setPen(QPen(self.brushColor, self.brushSize, Qt.SolidLine))

        if self.instrument == 'brush':
            for p in self.brush_points:
                painter.drawPoint(p)

        elif self.instrument == 'line':
            painter.drawLine(self.start_pos, self.end_pos)

        elif self.instrument == 'circle':
            painter.drawEllipse(QRectF(self.start_pos, self.end_pos))

        elif self.instrument == 'rectangle':
            painter.drawRect(QRectF(self.start_pos, self.end_pos))

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawImage(self.image_foreground.rect(), self.image_foreground)

        # Рисуем на виджете
        self.draw(self)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.start_pos = event.pos()
        self.brush_points.clear()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton:
            self.end_pos = event.pos()
            self.brush_points.append(self.end_pos)

            self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.end_pos = event.pos()
        self.brush_points.append(self.end_pos)

        # При отпускании кнопки мышки рисуем на картинке
        self.draw(self.image_foreground)
        self.update()

    def setBrush(self):
        self.instrument = 'brush'

    def setLine(self):
        self.instrument = 'line'

    def setCircle(self):
        self.instrument = 'circle'

    def setRectangle(self):
        self.instrument = 'rectangle'

    def four(self):
        self.brushSize = 4

    def eight(self):
        self.brushSize = 8

    def sixteen(self):
        self.brushSize = 16

    def thirtytwo(self):
        self.brushSize = 32

    def blackColor(self):
        self.brushColor = Qt.black

    def redColor(self):
        self.brushColor = Qt.red

    def blueColor(self):
        self.brushColor = Qt.blue

    def yellowColor(self):
        self.brushColor = Qt.yellow


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    wnd = Window()
    wnd.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

---

**PS.**

Сделал я как-то ранее простую рисовалку, возможно, она будет интересна вам: https://github.com/gil9red/fake-painter

Comment: А как сделать так, чтобы вставленная фотография растягивалась на весь холст?

Comment: @r64, как вариант, в `getImage` загрузите картинку в новый `QImage` (типа `img = QImage()` `img.load(...)`) и там вызовите `painter = QPainter(self.image_foreground)` с `painter.drawImage`. И заполните параметры `drawImage` как в прошлом вопросе, по-моему, должно быть так: `painter.drawImage(self.image_foreground.rect(), img, img.rect())`

Comment: Здравствуйте, извините что надоедаю, но можете поподробней объяснить, что вы делаете в методах draw, paintevent, mousePress/Move/Release Event. Буду очень благодарен

Comment: @r64, в `mousePressEvent` запоминаю текущую позицию курсора, чтобы знать откуда начать рисовать (а т.к. точки нужно рисовать непрерывно, то используем self.brush_points для сохранения списка точек). В mouseMoveEvent мы запоминаем вторую позицию мышки и вручную вызываем update, чтобы окно перерисовалось и вызвало paintEvent. В paintEvent мы рисуем текущую картинку (холст) и, по ранее запомненным координатам, фигуры на самом виджете, чтобы была возможность изменить финальную точку пока курсор мышки не отпустили. В mouseReleaseEvent мы рисуем уже окончательно. А draw это общий метод рисования

Comment: А как сделать так, чтобы была отдельная кнопка, которая отматывала действия назад, и еще одна, котрая возвращала их? То есть если я нарисовал что-то не в том месте, то я могу спокойно вернуться с помощью этой кнопки на шаг назад(и если что вернуть)

Comment: Помните, я скидывал ссылку на рисовальщик? Там это было сделано через копии `QImage`. Т.е. перед тем как рисовать на картинке сделаем ее копию и сохраним список (стек). А если хотим вернуть изменение, то берем последнюю картинку из списка (`.pop()`) кладем в переменную (холст) и вызываем обновление виджета (`self.update()`), чтобы он перерисовался

Comment: Да, я как раз недавно пытался взять из этого кода пару идей, но уже несколько дней программа выдает ошибку и не запускается.. поэтому обратился к вам за помощью

Comment: Ну... если сделаете новый вопрос с этой проблемой и скинете сюда ссылку на него, то могу посмотреть :)

Comment: Вот только тут с sqlite3 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1204768/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%91%d0%b4-%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4